# button sends output of variable to textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to click in a button, which will send the output of  a variable(cat list.txt) to a textarea. Actually, I will have 3 buttons.

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec('cat LIST.txt');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <br>
        <textarea placeholder="List Status" name="List" rows="30" cols="100" id="myTextarea"></textarea>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = "<?php echo "<pre>$output</pre>";?>";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: `shell_exec` can be replaced with `file_get_contents`

Comment: @Syscall Indeed.  Good grief that's ugly though  :)

Comment: Yes @PatrickQ, it's mostly quite confusing :)

Comment: I can display list.txt in textarea if I set it to display the content of the file, but not able to send data to textarea if I click a button.  file_get_contents  did not work.

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors?  What is the rendered HTML/JS for your code above?

Comment: I removed all errors that was shown in the browser, but still not working.  looks like it is not accepting "<?php echo '$output';?>.  It prints "$output" in textarea.